# sudo service apparmor restart gives error

Tags: server, home-directory, minecraft

Can someone please help me with this error?

```
root@ip3:~# sudo service apparmor restart
Job for apparmor.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apparmor.service" and "journalctl -xeu apparmor.service" for details.
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `systemctl status apparmor.service`? Also, why did you want to start apparmor? What are you trying to do?

Comment: pterodactyl server panel

Comment: same situation happend when i tried this: systemctl status apparmor.service